# Extract the name of subfolders and files after successful remote to local synchronization with WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

My work uses WinSCP .NET assembly for SFTP transfers. After successful transfer files from server to local, I want to list only names (without paths) of the files and folders that were synchronized.

I'm working with PowerShell.

This is my tree structure of my remote files: `/home/etc/`
Folders: `foldername1`, `foldername2`. Under every `foldername?`, I have files `matricule*.pdf`

```
foldername1 
   ----> matricule12455-126.pdf 
   ----> matricule12456-125.pdf
foldername2 
   ----> matricule1249-127.pdf 
   ----> matricule1241-128.pdf
```

I tried with this script:

```
$filename = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($download.FileName)
Write-Host "*** $filename ***" 
$matr = (Split-Path -Path $filename -Leaf).Split(".")[0];
Write-Host "*** $matr ***"
```

It shows whole path:

```
/home/etc/foldername1/matricule12455-126.pdf
matricule12455-126
```

And as a result I want to have this:

```
foldername1-12455-126
foldername1-12456-125
foldername2-1249-127 
foldername2-1241-128
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SynchronizationResult.Downloads`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_synchronizationresult#downloads) to get the list of all downloaded files. The full path to the source file is in [`TransferEventArgs.FileName`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transfereventargs#filename).

Then iterate the list, removing synchronization root path from the file path and doing other modifications you need:

```
$localPath = "c:\local\path"
$remotePath = "/remote/path"

# Bitvise SFTP
$results = $session.SynchronizeDirectories(
    [WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Local, $localPath, $remotePath, $False)
$results.Check()

$remotePath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::AddDirectorySeparator($remotePath)

foreach ($download in $results.Downloads)
{
    $filename = $download.FileName
    if (-not $filename.StartsWith($remotePath))
    {
        # Should never happen
        Write-Host "File path $filename does not start with root path $remotePath"
    }
    else
    {
        # Remove synchronization root path from the file path
        $filename = $filename.SubString($remotePath.Length)
        # Replace path separators with dashes
        $filename = $filename.Replace("/", "-")
        # Remove "matricule"
        $filename = $filename.Replace("matricule", "")
        # Remove file extension (it would also remove file path, but there is none)
        $filename = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($filename)
        Write-Host $filename
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
foldername1-12455-126
foldername1-12456-125
foldername2-1241-128
foldername2-1249-127
```